# why cant i simply copy n paste this to every page to have nav bar+logo?

Tags: html, css, navigation, styles, stylesheet

why cant I paste this to any .html doc and have it run right only in resources tab?
The logo only displays on the resources page, even though it is the same css stylesheet referenced in, as well as the same html copied.

```
<div class="navigate">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="logo" src="logo2.png"></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news2.html">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="resources2.html" class="dropbtn">Resources</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">MINING</a>
                <a href="#">CURRENCY</a>
                <a href="#">TRADING</a>
                <a href="#">LINKS</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    <ul>    
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="search2.html" class="dropbtn">Equipment</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">GPU</a>         
                <a href="#">ASIC</a>
                <a href="#">MOTHERBOARD</a>
                <a href="#">ACCESORIES</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there is an error in retrieving the image? If this is the case it could be because your other html files are in a different location (folder) than resources which would make the img src path different.

Comment: lol I forgot i move the pages to a folder and im working off desktop

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using relative paths for the `src` for the logo `img`, it is likely that your file structure is the issue.

Your .html files need to be in the same directory as the `logo2.png` in order for them to find that image